# Dart combining elements in one number

Tags: list, flutter, android-studio, dart, math

I have a list containing few elements like this: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]. I want to combine these numbers into one number without summing them so I want the final number to be: 112233; Is there a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use reduce method from list

```
List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  String s = "";
  for(int i in list) {
    s += i.toString();
  }
int result = int.parse(s); //result = 12345678910
```

result maximum value is 2^63-1, otherwise you will get an overflow!!!

Comment: `[for (var i in list) i.toString()].join()` is generally more efficient than doing repeated string concatenation.

Comment: @jamesdlin why not simply `list.join()`?

Comment: @mmcdon20 Good point, that's even better.  I forgot that `Iterable.join()` calls `.toString()` on each element already.

Comment: @jamesdlin It's almost like that. Except when the element is already a string. It is more correct, in this case, to say that each element goes through an internal string interpolation procedure. `final String elementString = "$nextElement";` => `static String _interpolateSingle(Object? o)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`list.join()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.2/dart-core/Iterable/join.html) method:

```
List<int> list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3];
String concatList = list.join().toString();
print(concatList);
```

Comment: Yeah. Someone does not even know about the existence of this method, but I use it instead of `StringBuffer` in parsers, because, as tests show, this method works faster than `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Oh. This is redundant `join().toString())`. This is enough `join()`.